# Как получить список контактов в Qt на Android

Tags: java, android, c++

Я написал простую функцию на java в Android Studio, которая склеивает список контактов в строку. Данные хранятся в xml. Сама функция работает отлично. Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать её в Qt через `QAndroidJniObject`, выдаёт ошибки.   Если удалить из функции весь код и оставить один `return`, то значение передастся... Пожалуйста, помогите вытянуть эту строку в C++

```
public String getcontactlist() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[ {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);     //Запрос прав на получение контактов
                                      String fetch = "<root>";     //Создание строки и корневого элемента
                                      Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                                              null);               //Получаю телефоны

    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        fetch += "<item><name>" + name + "</name><number>" + phoneNumber +
                 "</number></item>";//В цикле приписываю к строке
    }
    fetch += "</root>"; добавляю закрывающий тег
             return fetch; //Возвращаю значение
}
```

Кроме самой функции, отправляю исходник проекта на Qt. Пожалуйста, помогите получить список контактов https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B434-oBPl5BmTV9vbFNHa0xGamc

Вызов происходит через слот C++ класса BackEnd. Сама java функция находится в android/src/com/example/contacts/fetch/ в файле `FetchClass.java` и имеет заголовок `getContacts`

Comment: можно получить список контактов без java - [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255377/how-to-obtain-contact-list-in-qt)

Comment: Так QtMobility не имеет поддержки Android, тут как раз и надо использовать jni... Более того, поддержка Qt Mobility больше не ведется. На официальной странице документации Qt нет ни слова про контакты... http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/mobiledevelopment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё, написал. Вот репо с примером вызова кода на java. Он вернёт строку с контактами в xml. После парсим в qml и готово
https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qmlcontactlist